# Iothub module authentication error in Azure

Tags: azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-edge

I am running a fairly basic Azure IoT C# module. Initially, it all worked fine. However, when I set up X.509 certificates for the edge hub, I've been getting module authentication errors as follows. There seems to be some dependence on using Tcp_only or Websocket_only options of the AMQP/MQTT protocols (where the latter does not throw the exception), but this is not consistent across modules.

The offending lines of code are below
..

```
// Open a connection to the Edge runtime
        ioTHubModuleClient = await ModuleClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync(settings);
        await ioTHubModuleClient.OpenAsync();
```

The error message is below. Essentially the await times out because authentication is not complete. Far as I know, authentication is derived directly from the iot edge runtime, so not sure why it was specifically trying to authenticate or erroring out...

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. (The remote certificate is invalid according to the
>   validation procedure.) --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.InternalClient.<>c.b__62_2(Task
>   t) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task&
>   currentTaskSlot) --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at SampleModule.Program.d__10.MoveNext() in
>   /app/Program.cs:line 69 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   SampleModule.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/Program.cs:line 41

Comment: [X509-CA authentication over WebSocket is not supported](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp#key-features-and-roadmap). Is it your issue? What do you mean **the latter** in this sentence "where **the latter** does not throw the exception"?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT, 1. The "WebSocket_only" option does NOT throw the exception whereas the "TCP_only" option does. Far as I know, instantiating the module object should not require X.509 authentication since credentials are derived from the IoT edge runtime? However, my observation is that this module used to work without error, and now I see these problems. The only difference I can think of is that I set up X.509 certificates for the edge device in the meantime. That may be a red herring, though.

Comment: It seems edge device only support symmetric key authentication but not support x509 certificate authentication. So how do you set up x509 certificate for the edge device?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT, I was only trying to set up my edge to act as a transparent gateway, using the steps in the MSFT Azure tutorial here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-transparent-gateway-linux].

Comment: I wonder why you add a custom module(SampleModule) to a transparent gateway that [Edge Hub is the only module you need on an Edge Device to have it act as a transparent gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-transparent-gateway-linux#deploy-edgehub-to-the-gateway). Ref:"[How an IoT Edge device can be used as a gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-as-gateway)".